# Поворот картинки canvas + js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте.
Недавно нашёл функцию для поворота картинки, но проблема в том, что мне нужно установить таймер на поворот картинки, а здесь она крутиться бесконечно.
Я так понимаю, что всё дело в **arguments.callee**, о котором в Интернете дельной информации не нашёл. Есть ли варианты, чтобы функция один раз повернула картинку?
Найденная функция:

```
function CanvasCenter(){
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function(){
 var dl = i.width;
var cnv=document.getElementById("ci");
var c = cnv.getContext("2d");
   c.drawImage(i, 0, 0, dl, dl);
       var beta = -3;          
var beta = (beta*Math.PI)/360;
var bet=0;     
var x=100;
var y=100;                          
setTimeout(function(){
  bet+=beta;
c.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
c.save();
c.translate(x,y);
c.rotate(bet);
c.drawImage(i, -dl/2, -dl/2);
c.restore();
setTimeout(arguments.callee,10);
                 },0);
}
i.src = "image.png";
};
```

**Хочу её вставить в этот код, чтобы мог контролировать количество поворотов и задержку между ними:**

```
count = 0;

intervalId = setInterval(function(){
 count++;
 if(count == 100){
   clearInterval(intervalId);
 }
 CanvasCenter();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: Функция работает бесконечно из-за того что она постоянно сама себя взывает в `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10)`. Кстати почему вы делаете это через js. Не проще ли воспользоваться **CSS** [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) и [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)?